# $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos nx \, dx$ is always 0 when actually integrated.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

It's pretty apparent $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos nx \, dx$ should be 2$\pi$ when *n* = 0. However it seems $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos nx \, dx$ is always 0 when actually integrated **given that *n* is integer**. I have no idea why we can't get the same answer.

$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos nx \, dx& = \left [\frac{1}{n} \sin nx \right ]_{-\pi}^\pi 
\\&= \frac{1}{n} \sin n\pi - \frac{1}{n} sin {(-n\pi)}
\\&= \frac{1}{n} \sin n\pi + \frac{1}{n} \sin n\pi
\\&= \frac{2}{n} \sin n\pi
\\&= 0
\end{align}
$

Comment: Your steps aren't valid if $n = 0$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Why is that?

Comment: You would be dividing by zero.

Comment: You have to treat the $n=0$ case separately. Notice that you divided by $n$. You cannot do this if $n=0$. So what you should do is substitute $n=0$ directly into the integrand. You will have your answer from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if $n=0,$ then what can $\frac1n\sin nx$ even mean?

For non-zero constants $\alpha,$ we certainly have $\frac1\alpha\sin\alpha x$ as an antiderivative of $\cos\alpha x;$ however, if $\alpha=0,$ then $\cos\alpha x=1$ for all $x,$ and so does not have a periodic antiderivative.